# Persisting State from a DRPC Spout in Trident

Tags: clojure, apache-storm, trident

I'm experimenting with Storm and Trident for this project, and I'm using Clojure and Marceline to do so. I'm trying to expand the wordcount example given on [the Marceline page](https://github.com/yieldbot/marceline), such that the sentence spout comes from a DRPC call rather than from a local spout. I'm having problems which I think stem from the fact that the DRPC stream needs to have a result to return to the client, but I would like the DRPC call to effectively return null, and simply update the persisted data.

```
(defn build-topology
  ([]
   (let [trident-topology (TridentTopology.)]
     (let [
           ;; ### Two alternatives here ###
           ;collect-stream (t/new-stream trident-topology "words" (mk-fixed-batch-spout 3))
            collect-stream (t/drpc-stream trident-topology "words")
          ]
          (-> collect-stream
              (t/group-by ["args"])
              (t/persistent-aggregate (MemoryMapState$Factory.)
                                      ["args"]
                                      count-words
                                      ["count"]))
          (.build trident-topology)))))
```

There are two alternatives in the code - the one using a fixed batch spout loads with no problem, but when I try to load the code using a DRPC stream instead, I get this error:

```
InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [b-2] subscribes from non-existent component [$mastercoord-bg0])
```

I believe this error comes from the fact that the DRPC stream must be trying to subscribe to an output in order to have something to return to the client - but `persistent-aggregate` doesn't offer any such outputs to subscribe to.

So how can I set up my topology so that a DRPC stream leads to my persisted data being updated?

*Minor update*: Looks like this might not be possible :( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-38